# Avoiding sin() calls in audio synth

Tags: algorithm, audio, trigonometry

A naive sine wave generator takes a set of n values and calls the sin function on each of them:

```
for i = 0; i < 2*pi ; i = i+step {
    output = append(output, sin(i) )
}
```

However, this makes a lot of calls to a potentially expensive sin function, and fails to take advantage of the fact that all the samples are sequential, have been calculated previously, and will be rounded to an integer (PCM). So, what alternatives are there?

I'm imagining something along the lines of [Bresenham's circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) or pre-computing a high-res sample, and then downsizing by taking every n'th entry, but if there's an 'industrial strength' solution to this problem, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You seem to mention in your question that the sin() values will be rounded to the nearest integer. Is this true?

Comment: Ah, should have clarified. This is going into a wav-encoder, so it's PCM. Hence, any floating point value is going to wind up as a signed 16-bit int.

Comment: How fine of frequency resolution do you need?

Comment: Say 44khz sampling rate and a lower threshold of 10 Hz, which corresponds to a minimum step of 4.4 mrad (I think).

Comment: A very impressive approximation for sin can be found at http://devmaster.net/posts/9648/fast-and-accurate-sine-cosine. Don't know if the accuracy is good enough for audio applications though.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Good post. Diagrams are dead-linked, but the substance is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the vector z which gives you (cos theta, sin theta) when you add to (1,0), where theta = 2*pi/step. Then you add this vector to (1,0) and get the next  sin value as the y-coordinate of the sum. Then you rotate z by angle theta (by multiplying by the rotation matrix through angle theta) and add this to your previous vector (cos theta, sin theta), to get the next sin value as the y-coordinate of the resultant sum vector. And so forth. This requires computing cos theta and sin theta just once, and then each update is given by a matrix multiplication of a 2x2 matrix with a 2-d vector, and then a simple addition, which is faster than computing sin() using the power series expansion.

Comment: Nice technique. Probably wise to do this at double precison to avoid buildup of roundoff errors.

Comment: Agreed on the precision issue, I thought about that and couldn't come up with a slick solution to the roundoff issue, so the roundoff error is currently unavoidable, although it will be negligible if step isn't too small and double precision is used.

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded like nitpicking, I was just pointing out to the casual reader that this an example where one should avoid using single precision as an 'optimization'.

Comment: Benchmarked naive vs. the above in golang (using the math.Sin function as the reference). Speed up of about 4x, and a pretty neglible avg. error of ~5e-11 over 10000 iterations, but the error does compound without handling. Good stuff.